# Rails nested form 3rd level not saving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a user who can have many reservations and each reservation can have many tables. It saves the user and the reservations, but not the tables. Tables can have special requirements, like wheelchair accessible or kids high chair etc.

**Models**

User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tables, through: :reservations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservations, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tables, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Reservations:

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tables
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tables, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Tables:

```
class Table < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reservation
end
```

The form structure looks like this:

**Views**

user/_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
   .row
     .col-6
       = f.input :last_name, required: true
   .row
     .col-6
       = f.input :first_name
     .col-6
       = f.input :email

... some more here

    = f.simple_fields_for :reservations do |res|
       = render 'reservations/reservations_fields', f: res
       .links
         = link_to_add_association 'add reservation', f, :reservations, partial: 'reservations/reservations_fields'
```

reservations/_reservations_fields.html.slim:

```
.form-inputs
  .row
    .col-6
      = f.input :reservation_datetime, as: :datetime, minute_step: 15

... some more here

  .row
    = f.simple_fields_for :tables do |table|
      .col-12
        = render 'tables/form', f: table
```

tables/_form.html.slim:

```
.nested-fields
  .form-inputs
    .row
      .col-6
        = f.input :wheelchair
... etc
```

**Controller**

users_controller.rb

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :email, :company, :comments,
           reservations_attributes: [:id, :reservation_datetime, :important, :head_count, :comments,
              tables_attributes: [:id, :wheelchair, :children, :comments]])
  end
```

Why are the table attributes not saving? I cannot find the mistake.

Edit: I want to add that it saves the association, but NOT the attributes. Thank you

Edit 2: The params are sent to the UserController (I checked with byebug), but they don't get saved.

byebug:

```
(byebug) user_params
<ActionController::Parameters {[...], "comments"=>"", "reservations_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters { [...], "tables_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {"wheelchair"=>"0", "children"=>"2", "comments"=>""} permitted: true>} permitted: true>} permitted: true>} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

But the SQL statement is

```
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:42:in `create'
  Tables Create (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "tables" ("reservation_id") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["reservation_id", 12]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:42:in `create'
   (2.0ms)  COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the problem wasn't because it was third-level nested. The real problem was that I used `attr_accessor` in my tables model. When I removed this, it suddenly worked. Don't know why though, will open another question regarding this.